# How to force Firefox Nightly to install an addon?

Tags: firefox-for-android, browser-add-ons

Firefox Nightly refuses to install addons unless Mozilla "recommends" them. That's an artificial restriction.[1] How to bypass it?

[1] https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-compatibility-firefox-preview#w_extension-compatibility-for-firefox-preview

Comment: Did you find: https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/developing-extensions-for-firefox-for-android/

Comment: @Morrison Chang doesn't work, "Firefox Nightly can't download this file type". Opening it from a file manager doesn't work either. `xpinstall.signatures.required` is disabled although I didn't expect that to help.

Comment: See a hack here: https://old.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/i8igam/androidrequires_root_install_any_addon_from_amo/